# plugins for gedit in python

Tags: python, plugins, pygtk, gedit

I've been trying to learn to write plugins for gedit 3.x in python and I'm facing a lot of difficulties in it. 
I want to know whether there are some things you should know beforehand (like PyGTK) to make learning easier or are there some good resources to learn writing plugins for gedit.
I've tried https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo and studying some plugin code like bracket completion. What should be my approach?
Any help/tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly suggest checking out the [gmate project](https://github.com/gmate/gmate). It is a suite of plugins for gedit, most of which are built in python. Of course, public repositories on github are open-source and, therefore, you can feel free to use their code if you wish. Perhaps seeing how they did it will provide you with some helpful insight.

Comment: Should i learn PyGTK, I'm pretty sure to make plugins dealing with menus and buttons it is neccessary. I am mainly interested in manipulating the text of files to make programs like bracket completion.

Comment: It would probably be helpful. Looking into gmate's source I noticed some .glade files, which implies that pyGTK is used. I would suggest the use of glade, I use it for developing in PyGTK and it makes working much easier.

Answer (score 3):

[My tutorial on writing plugins for Gedit 3](http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html) should get you up and running.

Gedit 3 uses GTK+ 3 which means that it uses PyGObject not PyGTK. PyGTK was the python bindings for GTK+ 2.

The [Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a good place to learn the specifics of Python and GTK+ 3 (PyGObject).